# useEffect not triggering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I think my useEffect is broken.

I have on the parent component

```
 <div className={redactKategori}>
    <select className="form-control form-control-sm mb-3 mr-2" name="betalt" defaultValue={'välj kategori'} onChange={e => { e.preventDefault(); setKate(e.target.value); setRedactKategoris('d-block') }}>
      <option >valj kategori</option>
      { Kategori ?
        Object.keys(Kategori).map(key => {
          return (
            <option key={key} value={key}>{key}</option>
          )
        }) :
        null
      }
      </select>
    <div className={redactKategoris}>
  <EditKat aa={kate} />
</div>
```

and on the child component

```
function EditKat({ aa }) {
  let defaultValues = 0

  useEffect(() => {
    defaultValues = 2
  }, [aa])

  console.log(defaultValues)
}
```

So, as far as I understood, everytime `${kate}` would get a value on the parent component, the child component would trigger the `useEffect` hook. However it is not working. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Dont directly change the defaultValues. Instead use `useState()` and update the default values using set.

Comment: @Praveenkumar it is not simply. DefaultValues here was a simple example, but it is gonna even be more complex, because defaultValues will only be rendered if other variable can be defined from redux

Comment: Your `useEffect` should be called once the component mounts, and every time `aa` changes. To ensure `useEffect` is never called, try `console.log` inside of it, because as pointed out by Praveenkumar, you cannot rely on the render (because your are not re-rendering your component by doing `defaultValues = 2`)

Comment: Just to be sure: you don't see any change in the UI, or you don't enter in the `useEffect` at all? (You can put a `console.log()` there, or a breakpoint).

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the experienced behavior is not that `useEffect` isn't working. It's because of the way function components work.

If you look at your child component, if `useEffect` is executed and the component rerenders, `defaultValues` would be set to `0` again, because the code inside of the function is executed on each render cycle.

To work around that, you would need to use the `useState` to keep your local state consistent across renders.

This would look something like this:

```
function EditKat({ aa }) {
  // Data stored in useState is kept across render cycles
  let [defaultValues, setDefaultValues] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    setDefaultValues(2) // setDefaultValues will trigger a re-render
  }, [aa])

  console.log(defaultValues)
}
```

Comment: That's indeed correct. I'd like to add that, if you do NOT want to trigger an update, you can use `React.useRef()`, which allows you to mantain consistent values outside the re-render lifecycle (https://it.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a key prop on your component when it is created in the parent code

```
<yourcomponent key="uniquevalue" />
```

This is because in most cases, when your component is reused, based on the way it is created, it may usually re-render it with some changes instead of recreating it again when you reuse it, Hence the `useEffect` is not going to be called. eg in SwitchRoute, loops, conditionals...

So adding a key will prevent this from happening. If it is in a loop make sure each element is unique, maybe by including the index `i` in the key if you can't find any better unique key.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, I debugged it and i found that, i am mutating the state directly instead of cloning it and using it. So, that's why useEffect is not triggered.